# Is Word2Vec itself a discriminative model or a generative model?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, statistics, data-science, word2vec

I am wondering whether Word2Vec itself is a discriminative model or generative model?

Both CBOW and Skip-gram aim at maximizing likelihood function corresponding to conditional probabilities between tokens and their contexts. Only focusing on the network and the training process, I suppose it follows a discriminative approach.

However, the word embedding is kind of a by-product, which depicts the relationships between tokens in the training corpus. Considering a Word2Vec model, which is trained with a segmented corpus, takes in a token and outputs its embedding, we often say that 'it generates a word embedding'. Is a Word2Vec model a discriminative one or a generative one?

I have met with some trouble formulating it.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between generative and discriminative models is that generative models describe *a joint distribution* of its inputs and outputs, whereas discriminative describe *a conditional distribution* of outputs given inputs.

Word2Vec is thus trained **discriminatively**: in CBOW, we predict a word given its context, the skip-gram model works the other way round.

When you say that it generates an embedding it is a different sense of "generate", it does not mean sampling from a joint distribution, but rather generating in general.

My opinion is that once the embeddings are trained, it does not make much sense to talk about it as a discriminative (nor generative) model because you only use the representation, not the probability distribution that the model defines.

Comment: I suppose we agree on that the training process of Word2Vec is discriminative. However, I am just wondering how to formulate the representation generation process. (As you said, the sense of word 'generation' is more general here.)  Always, we use the output of whatever discriminative or generative model. The representation is the output. The discussion about whether a model is discriminative or generative focuses on what the model defines and how the output is generated. Thus, I am still kind of curious about how to classify the Word2Vec model.

Comment: More specifically, from my perspective, for discriminative models we only focus on conditional probabilities and use conditional probabilities, while for generative models we define joint probabilities but still when generating outputs with given inputs, conditional probabilities are used with the help of Bayesian Theorem. Whether the joint distribution is considered is the key to the classification criteria. I am confused and feel it hard to formulate when it comes to Word2Vec.

Comment: Well, there is no generating in the probabilistic sense. There is no distribution over the representations, it is basically a lookup table. So, it is neither discriminative nor generative, it is a lookup table and not a probabilistic model.

Comment: Em...I suppose here comes another ambiguity issue. In daily life, we may say that some event is probabilistic or deterministic. The two kinds of events are basically mutually exclusive. However, mathematically, when we interpret things with probability theory, everything is probabilistic and every collection of items/instances has a distribution, certainly so does the 'lookup table' you named. Actually, any model with finite effective inputs is somehow 'basically a lookup table' if we pre-calculate all the outputs after optimization within the training process.